# O Observable não está aceitando o Catch

Tags: angular

Obsevem a figura abaixo;
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por que será que o Observable não está aceitando o **catch**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para utilizar o operador 'Catch', é necessário importa-lo da biblioteca do rxjs desta maneira:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

Assim você conseguirá utiliza-lo.

Answer (score -1):

Como o Observable é assíncrono, o try/catch não funciona. Você deve definir um callback de erro como o exemplo abaixo da [documentação do angular](https://angular.io/guide/observables):

```
myObservable.subscribe({
  next(num) { console.log('Next num: ' + num)},
  error(err) { console.log('Received an errror: ' + err)}
});
```

Comment: eu coloquei como correta, mas realmente resolvi o meu problema colocando essa importação 

import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';